# How to move particular controller action log from production.log to test.log ? Ruby 1.8.7 Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**For example :**
Processing TestController#test_action (for 00.00.00.00 at 2018-03-21 11:37:52) [POST]
Parameters: {"action"=>"test_action", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"test", "authenticity_token"=>"***************************************"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Completed in 23277ms (View: 000, DB: 000) | 200 OK [https://localhost.test/test/test_action/11]

**Expected behavior**

*Above log comes in front on me 1000's of times when I do tail -f log/production.log to see my production logs, and because of the above action, I wasnt able to check my other important logs which are few in number, so I want to move the particular controller action log to another new log file which makes my logging experience better.*

**System configuration**

**Rails version:**
2.3
**Ruby version:**
1.8.7

Please help.

Comment: How about you call `tail -f log/production.log | grep -v TestController` - this way you will filter out logs you don't want to see, and you don't need to change the behaviour of your application?

Comment: @arnvald nice suggestion but it will remove only one line, how can i remove the remaining lines
Parameters: {"action"=>"test_action", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"test", "authenticity_token"=>"***************************************"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Completed in 23277ms (View: 000, DB: 000) | 200 OK [https://localhost.test/test/test_action/11]

Comment: How about `grep -v test_action`?

Comment: Brilliant, very close to the temporary solution.But It was little bit of helpful, Wasn't able separate the logs which actually i want.

Comment: While you could create a piece of middleware that redirects the log output if the request matches a certain criteria its a pretty crappy solution to something that should be solved with proper tooling. In development you can use Railspanel in chrome to get get the log output in the browser. For production you can use New Relic.

Comment: Thanks @max , tooling is the great idea.I have to see how they works. But i m in search of a way to move separate particular action logs in RAILS, so that it is easy to maintain, and view it.

Comment: The problem is that its not really a good idea - configuration like logging is usually done on per server basis - not per request. While it can be done with middleware I doubt that you will find a ready made solution because its a bad idea that can solved properly by just using development/managing tools.

Comment: If you know the logs you "really want", then why not write **those** to a different file, explicitly? (Or, grep for them explicitly?)